# Pivot data with sequence order and group by values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

In a SQL Server data warehouse table, in sequence for a given detail find the V,T,C `group by Shipment_id order by TASK_SEQUENCE_NUMBER` where the order of `TASK_TYPE` is V then T then C.

This value can be 0 if there is no values for V,T,C in sequence In case of V,T,C is more than once, we can sum the values and display

Below is the table schema and data with the result expected which has to be incorporated in a stored procedure with more columns in the `Task_Main` Table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Task_Detail]
(
    [Task_Sid] [int] NULL,      
    [Shipment_ID] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [TASK_SEQUENCE_No] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [TASK_TYPE] [varchar](1) NULL,      
    [TASK_DURATION] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,      
    [LOCATION_CODE] [varchar](15) NULL,         
    [TaskStart] [bigint] NULL    
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Task_Header]
(
    [Task_Sno] [int] NULL,      
    [Shipment_ID] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Vehicle_Id] [nchar](10) NULL,      
    [DepotVisitStartTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,      
    [Time_V] [bigint] NULL,         
    [Time_T] [bigint] NULL,     
    [Time_C] [bigint] NULL     
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT [dbo].[Task_Detail] ([Task_Sid], [Shipment_ID], [TASK_SEQUENCE_No], [TASK_TYPE], [TASK_DURATION], [LOCATION_CODE], [TaskStart]) 
VALUES (1, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'K', CAST(20 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'LC39', 20),
       (2, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(7 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'L', CAST(21 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019514', 21),
       (3, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'L', CAST(58 AS  Decimal(18, 0)), N'LC38', 58),
       (4, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(6 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'C', CAST(10 AS Decimal(18, 0)), NULL, 10),
       (5, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(8 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'V', CAST(30 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019514', 30),
       (6, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(10 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'C', CAST(11 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'RJC', 11),
       (7, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(9 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'T', CAST(19 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019027', 19),
       (8, CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(7 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'V', CAST(29 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10018952', 29),
       (9, CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(4 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'K', CAST(20 AS Decimal(18, 0)), NULL, 20),
       (10, CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(5 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'V', CAST(0 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'302', 0),
       (11, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(12 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'T', CAST(19 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019514', 19),
       (12, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(13 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'E', CAST(11 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019514', 11),
       (13, CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'V', CAST(32 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'', 32),
       (14, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(4 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'K', CAST(20 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10018952', 20),
       (15, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(5 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'V', CAST(0 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'LC57', 0),
       (16, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(8 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'T', CAST(19 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019514', 19),
       (17, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(9 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'C', CAST(10 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019027', 10),
       (18, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'L', CAST(21 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'LC38', 21),
       (19, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(11 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'V', CAST(30 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019514', 30),
       (20, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(10 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'L', CAST(21 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019514', 21),
       (21, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'T', CAST(19 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'LC39', 19),
       (22, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'C', CAST(10 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'302', 10),
       (23, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'V', CAST(0 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'302', 0),
       (24, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(4 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'V', CAST(29 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10018952', 29),
       (25, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(5 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'T', CAST(19 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'LC57', 19)
, (26, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(6 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'L', CAST(58 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019514', 58)
, (27, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(7 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'V', CAST(29 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019514', 29)
, (28, CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(6 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'L', CAST(58 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10018952', 58)
, (29, CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'L', CAST(35 AS Decimal(18, 0)), NULL, 35)



INSERT [dbo].[Task_Header] ([Task_Sno], [Shipment_ID], [Vehicle_Id], [DepotVisitStartTime], [Time_V], [Time_T], [Time_C]) VALUES 
(1, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'TN1       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T07:25:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(2, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'TN1       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T07:25:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(3, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'TN1       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T07:25:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(4, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'TN1       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T07:25:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(5, CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'KA2       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T06:12:52.0000000' AS DateTime2), NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(6, CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'KA2       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T06:12:52.0000000' AS DateTime2), NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(7, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'AP3       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T06:32:52.0000000' AS DateTime2), NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(8, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'AP3       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T06:32:52.0000000' AS DateTime2), NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(9, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'AP3       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T13:12:21.0000000' AS DateTime2), NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

Expected Result with filter:

Sort Data by Shipment_ID , TASK_SEQUENCE_NUMBER filter where Location_code <> 'RJC' Join of TaskMaster and TaskDetails is Shipment_id TASK_TYPE should be V in a given sequence, next immediate with T , next immediate with C only considered for output

Sample data : result
for Shipment_ID 1, we have the column V : 59 which is sum of "V" value for the given Shipment_Id result data is group by shipment_id which is sum of sequence_number 4 and 8 = 29+30 = 59
Column T is present in scequence after V which is sum of sequence_number 5 and 9 = 19 +19 = 38
Column C is present in scequence after T which is sum of sequence_number 6 and 10 = 10 +11 = 21
For shipment 2, we dont have Task Type in VTC Secquence
For shipment 3, we have Task Type in V T C Secquence for no 7 ,8 , 9 with values 29 , 19, 10 which is only once and that value is sent to main table

[image: Sample data with marking which has to considered]

```
Expected Result
-----------------------------
Sno Shipment_ID Vehicle ID  DepotVisitStartTime         V   T   C
1   1           TN1         2019-02-15 07:25:33.0000000 59  38  21
2   1           TN1         2019-02-15 07:25:33.0000000 59  38  21
3   1           TN1         2019-02-15 07:25:33.0000000 59  38  21
4   1           TN1         2019-02-15 07:25:33.0000000 59  38  21
5   2           KA2         2019-02-15 06:12:52.0000000 0   0   0
6   2           KA2         2019-02-15 06:12:52.0000000 0   0   0
7   3           AP3         2019-02-15 06:32:52.0000000 29  19  10
8   3           AP3         2019-02-15 06:32:52.0000000 29  19  10
9   3           AP3         2019-02-15 13:12:21.0000000 29  19  10
```

These columns are continuation of below post and I want to have a stored proceudre to insert data into Task_Master table [Aggregate Date and quantity in same table for given ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This produces the output you want as a `select`:

```
select h.*, coalesce(d.v, 0) as v,
       coalesce(d.t, 0) as t, coalesce(d.c, 0) as c
from task_header h outer apply
     (select sum(dv.task_duration) as v,
             sum(dt.task_duration) as t,
             sum(dc.task_duration) as c
      from task_detail dv join
           task_detail dt
           on dt.Shipment_ID = dv.Shipment_ID and dt.TASK_SEQUENCE_No = dv.TASK_SEQUENCE_No + 1 join
           task_detail dc
           on dc.Shipment_ID = dt.Shipment_ID and dc.TASK_SEQUENCE_No = dt.TASK_SEQUENCE_No + 1 
      where dv.Shipment_ID = h.Shipment_ID and dv.task_type = 'V' and dt.task_type = 'T' and dc.task_type = 'C'
     ) d;
```

This does an update:

```
update h
    set time_v = coalesce(d.v, 0),
        time_t = coalesce(d.t, 0),
        time_c = coalesce(d.c, 0)
from task_header h outer apply
     (select sum(dv.task_duration) as v,
             sum(dt.task_duration) as t,
             sum(dc.task_duration) as c
      from task_detail dv join
           task_detail dt
           on dt.Shipment_ID = dv.Shipment_ID and dt.TASK_SEQUENCE_No = dv.TASK_SEQUENCE_No + 1 join
           task_detail dc
           on dc.Shipment_ID = dt.Shipment_ID and dc.TASK_SEQUENCE_No = dt.TASK_SEQUENCE_No + 1 
      where dv.Shipment_ID = h.Shipment_ID and dv.task_type = 'V' and dt.task_type = 'T' and dc.task_type = 'C'
     ) d;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=79513582f6a1342b285b0fa602bc6ca6) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I am using SQL DW
below is the error
Msg 104058, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
FROM clause in UPDATE and DELETE statements cannot contain subquery sources or joins.

Comment: @Raj . . . This code works.  I included the db<>fiddle.

Comment: Select is working fine.
Update is not working in SQL DW

Answer (score 0):

If you *do* have SQL Server 2012+ (I recommend you do, 2008 is about to fall completely out of support) then you can use `LEAD` to achieve this:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT TD.Task_Sid,
           TD.Shipment_ID,
           TD.TASK_SEQUENCE_No,
           TD.TASK_TYPE,
           TD.TASK_DURATION,
           LEAD(TASK_TYPE,1) OVER (PARTITION BY Shipment_ID ORDER BY TASK_SEQUENCE_No) AS NextType,
           LEAD(TASK_DURATION,1) OVER (PARTITION BY Shipment_ID ORDER BY TASK_SEQUENCE_No) AS NextDuration,
           LEAD(TASK_TYPE,2) OVER (PARTITION BY Shipment_ID ORDER BY TASK_SEQUENCE_No) AS NextNextType,
           LEAD(TASK_DURATION,2) OVER (PARTITION BY Shipment_ID ORDER BY TASK_SEQUENCE_No) AS NextNextDuration
    FROM Task_Detail TD),
VTC AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM CTE
    WHERE TASK_TYPE = 'V'
      AND NextType = 'T'
      AND NextNextType = 'C'
)
SELECT TH.Task_Sno,
       TH.Shipment_ID,
       TH.Vehicle_Id,
       TH.DepotVisitStartTime,
       ISNULL(SUM(TASK_DURATION),0) AS V,
       ISNULL(SUM(NextDuration),0) AS T,
       ISNULL(SUM(NextNextDuration),0) AS C
FROM Task_Header TH
     LEFT JOIN VTC ON TH.Shipment_ID = VTC.Shipment_ID
GROUP BY TH.Task_Sno,
         TH.Shipment_ID,
         TH.Vehicle_Id,
         TH.DepotVisitStartTime;
```

If not, then you'll need to do 3 scans of the table `Task_Detail`, which'll be more costly:

```
WITH VTC AS(
    SELECT TD1.Task_Sid,
           TD1.Shipment_ID,
           TD1.TASK_SEQUENCE_No,
           TD1.TASK_TYPE,
           TD1.TASK_DURATION,
           TD2.TASK_TYPE AS NextType,
           TD2.TASK_DURATION  AS NextDuration,
           TD3.TASK_TYPE AS NextNextType,
           TD3.TASK_DURATION  AS NextNextDuration
    FROM Task_Detail TD1
         JOIN Task_Detail TD2 ON TD1.Shipment_ID = TD2.Shipment_ID
                             AND TD1.TASK_SEQUENCE_No +1 = TD2.TASK_SEQUENCE_No
         JOIN Task_Detail TD3 ON TD1.Shipment_ID = TD3.Shipment_ID
                             AND TD1.TASK_SEQUENCE_No +2 = TD3.TASK_SEQUENCE_No
    WHERE TD1.TASK_TYPE = 'V'
      AND TD2.TASK_TYPE = 'T'
      AND TD3.TASK_TYPE = 'C')
SELECT TH.Task_Sno,
       TH.Shipment_ID,
       TH.Vehicle_Id,
       TH.DepotVisitStartTime,
       ISNULL(SUM(TASK_DURATION),0) AS V,
       ISNULL(SUM(NextDuration),0) AS T,
       ISNULL(SUM(NextNextDuration),0) AS C
FROM Task_Header TH
     LEFT JOIN VTC ON TH.Shipment_ID = VTC.Shipment_ID
GROUP BY TH.Task_Sno,
         TH.Shipment_ID,
         TH.Vehicle_Id,
         TH.DepotVisitStartTime;
```